# 5-digit numbers with at most one digit in common

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, optimization

5-digit numbers are created using the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Any two numbers can have at most one corresponding digit equal to each other.

> **How many different 5-digit numbers can you get in total that satisfy the above condition?**

if this question was asked for 3-digit with 3 different numbers, the answer will be 9.

- 111
- 212
- 223
- 122
- 231
- 313
- 133
- 321
- 332

Comment: Your example list chosen from three different numbers appears to be incorrect as, for example, it includes '111' (with three digits 'equal to each other') and does not include '331' (which has 'one digit equal to each other') - if I understand your requirements correctly.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. No two three digit numbers have identical digits in two or more locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the answer cannot exceed 25 since the number of distinct combination of two digits is 25 (11, 12, 13, .... 53, 54, 55).

> It turns out we can find a solution with exactly 25 numbers.

> First 2 digits must be all the 25 two-digit distinct pairs. Then note that for every starting digit, the five digits at any other position must be all distinct values. As you keep adding digits, additional conditions will be imposed. I tried cyclic shifts of 12345 for the 3rd, 4th and 5th positions for every starting digit and ended up with a solution.

> 11211
>  12322
>  13433
>  14544
>  15155
>  21334
>  22445
>  23551
>  24112
>  25223
>  31452
>  32513
>  33124
>  34235
>  35341
>  41525
>  42131
>  43242
>  44353
>  45414
>  51143
>  52254
>  53315
>  54421
>  55532

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple rule to generate such a set of numbers

> As Manish already explained, the first 2 digits must form distinct numbers among the numbers in the set because else you would have 2 digits in common.  So the best we can hope is to have one number for every 2 starting digits.  There are 25 of them.
>
>  A simple rule is to repeat the same difference between digits, mod 5.
>
>  If the first 2 digits are A and A+d, you continue A+2d A+3d and A+4d.  All of this modulo 5 (kind of, 0 is replaced by 5).
>
>  If two digits are in common between 2 numbers, then the 5 digits must be in common.
>
>  for example: 25??? will be 25314  (2+3=5, 5+3=8=3, 3+3=6=1, 1+3=4)
>
>  The complete set is:
>  11111 12345 13524 14253 15432
>  21543 22222 23451 24135 25314
>  31425 32154 33333 34512 35241
>  41352 42531 43215 44444 45123
>  51234 52413 53142 54321 55555